# Lower textfields embedded in scrollview not receiving touches

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, textfield

I have a lot of textfields arranged vertically in a scrollview and at the very bottom one textview.  All are wired in storyboard to outlets in a .h file and also to action methods that trigger a method to enable a save button.  All have their delegates set in viewdid load.  However, the bottom textfields--those below the bottom of the screen when it appears onscreen are not responding to touches.

The textfields visible when you open screen respond to touches. The fields below do not. This is baffling.  I am using autolayout but have tried all sorts of settings for the sizes of the view, contentview and scrollview without success.  Right now I have them all the same size (667 height).

Using the visual debugger I do not see any views blocking the textfields. I do see the scrollview being tapped. Since the scrollview has a gesture recognizer, I have put in code to screen against touches to the textfields with no luck.

Can anyone suggest what might be wrong?

```
Here is some code that might be relevant:
//in view will appear
//for dismissing keynoard from scroll
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapScroll = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self     action:@selector(tapped)];
    tapScroll.cancelsTouchesInView = TRUE;//was no
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tapScroll];

- (void) tapped
{
    NSLog(@"tapped fired");
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
//setting delegates
self.titleField.delegate=self;
    self.firstField.delegate=self;
    self.lastField.delegate = self;
    self.emailField.delegate=self;
    self.email2Field.delegate=self;
    self.telField.delegate=self;
    self.mobField.delegate=self;
    self.telmainField.delegate=self;
    self.teltollField.delegate=self;
    self.telhField.delegate=self;
    self.telfaxField.delegate=self;
    self.jobtitleField.delegate = self;
    self.coField.delegate = self;
    self.addr1Field.delegate = self;

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    NSLog(@"gesture recognizer should receive touch");

    // Disallow recognition of tap gestures in the segmented control.
    if ((touch.view == _titleField)||(touch.view == _firstField)||(touch.view == _lastField)||(touch.view == _emailField)||(touch.view == _email2Field)
        ||(touch.view == _telField)||(touch.view == _mobField)||(touch.view == _telmainField)||(touch.view == _teltollField)||(touch.view == _telhField)||(touch.view == _telfaxField)||(touch.view == _jobtitleField)||(touch.view == _coField)||(touch.view == _addr1Field)) {//change it to your condition
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1200);
}
```

Comment: Do the textfields appear outside of their parent view's bounds? you can verify this by setting the parent view's property ClipsToBounds to true, if the controls no longer appear they are outside of the bounds.  Touch events will not fire on controls outside of their parent views bounds even if they are visible onscreen.

Comment: the view hierarch is View:ScrollView:ContentView://various textfields. parentView would be ContentView?

Comment: Yes that may be it.  Lower items not visible after setting clips to bounds to yes.  I had set the contentView to the same size as the superview in autolayout and also set it to a large number in the measurement inspector but perhaps autolayout ignored those settings.  I'll try creating a height constraint and setting it to a large value.

Comment: I've had this problem before and my fix is to set the ContentView Left Right and Bottom anchors to View and the Top to ScrollView.

Comment: Hi, I don't see option to set bottom anchor of content view to view.  It only lets me set leading, trailing and top or center or set equal widths or heights.

Comment: Hey sorry I don't really know how to do this with storyboards, I use 100% swift and SnapKit to layout my views.